# PHP, cURL - Login to API (Request parameter 'password' is required)

Tags: php, api, curl, authentication, token

i try to Login to a API with the following Code

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$id = $_POST["id"]; 
$id2 = $_POST["id2"];               
// URL to fetch
$url = "https://bpk.bs.picturemaxx.com/api/v1/user/login";
// Setting the HTTP Request Headers
$User_Agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0';

$request_headers[] = 'X-picturemaxx-api-key: Key';
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Length:0';
$request_headers[] = 'Expect:  ';
$request_headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer token';

$username = "$id";
$password = "$id2";

$ch = curl_init($url);
// Set the url
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $User_Agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);

// Execute
$result = curl_exec($ch); // Performs the Request, with specified 
curl_setopt() options (if any).
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

When i run this code all i get is "Request parameter 'password' is required". A example body to login from the API-Website looks like this

```
{
  "password": "string",
  "username": "string"
}
```

and a example CURL looks like this

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'X-picturemaxx-api-key: key' -d '{ \ 
   "password": "pwd", \ 
   "username": "usrname" \ 
 }' 'https://bpk.bs.picturemaxx.com/api/v1/user/login'
```

How do I have to use the example body in PHP Curl to use the password so that the login works?
How can I continue to use the token created during login?

Thanks for solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. Here is my code if someone has similar difficulties

```
<?php
            header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

                // URL to fetch
                $url = "https://bpk.bs.picturemaxx.com/api/v1/user/login";
            // Setting the HTTP Request Headers
                $User_Agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0';

                $request_headers[] = 'X-picturemaxx-api-key: key';
                $request_headers[] = 'Contect-Type:text/html';
                $request_headers[] = 'Accept:text/html';
                $request_headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
                $request_headers[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
                $request_headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate, identity';
                $request_headers[] = 'Expect: ';                   

                $dataj = array (
  'password' => 'passwd',
  'username' => 'usrname',
);
                 $data_json = json_encode($dataj);
                 $request_headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json);


              $ch = curl_init($url);
              // Set the url      

        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $User_Agent);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");

                // Execute
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
              $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
 // Performs the Request, with specified curl_setopt() options (if any).
                //$data = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'php://input' ), true );

                // Closing
        curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($result, true);
if ($code == 200) {
    $result = json_decode($result, true);
    print_r($result);
} else {
    echo 'error ' . $code;
}

print_r($result);
print_r($data);         

?>
```

With this spelling it works now.

```
$dataj = array (
  'password' => 'passwd',
  'username' => 'usrname',
);
```

Another mistake was that I used $data_json in the header before initializing it.

```
$data_json = json_encode($dataj);
                 $request_headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see where are putting the **username** and **password**.
You have to add data to the cURL request.

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

Where $data is your array with username and password. And because the API is expecting json data, json_encode is used.

Comment: I've already tried that. $data = array('username'=>'usrname','password'=>'pwd'); and then curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data)); But still i get "Request parameter 'password' is required".

Comment: Try without the json_encode(). Sometimes the API implementation is taking the parameters from **POST** instead of reading them from **php://input**

Comment: I tried this curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);. But nothing changed. Maybe it has something to do with the spelling of username and password? Could it be? That you have to adapt it to the "Body" example from above?

Comment: CURLOP_POSTFIELDS is indeed the body of request.